# Drawing pies using PHP ImageMagick

Tags: php, graphics, imagemagick, draw

Is there a way to get  GD's function [`imagefilledarc()`'s](http://www.php.net/imagefilledarc) result in using PHP ImageMagick? I've looked around but haven't found a satisfying solution so far. I want it to support transparency, and use it to draw pies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this post gets hit by googlers every now and then, and doesn't have a valid answer, I figured I should give some hints. There is an excellent library called Imagine (https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) which supports the most popular PHP image libraries (ImageMagick, GraphicsMagick and GD) using the same calls.

It's API includes a pieSlice function (https://imagine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_static/API/Imagine/Draw/DrawerInterface.html#method_pieSlice). The source for that function is https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine/blob/develop/src/Imagick/Drawer.php#L242

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use ImageMagick::Draw.  It has an arc command; instead of specifying the center, you specify the bounding rectangle.  You just need to add a command before it to set the fill, and perhaps after it to close the fill.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagickdraw-arc.php

Comment: It doesn't work the same way. That command basically does an ellipse within the bounding box, cuts at a line between the given degrees and deletes one of the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ImagickDraw::arc is the only way to do it (unless you want to create a function that draws it pixel by pixel). But to get it working the same way as gd, you just have to make minor changes. For instance, this:

```
imagearc($image, $cx, $cy, $width, $height, $start, $end, $color);
```

Should be equivalent to this (I haven't tested it):

```
ImagickDraw::setStrokeColor($imageMagickColor);    //I don't remember how to allocate the color
ImagickDraw::arc($cx-$width/2, $cy-$height/2, $cx+$width/2, $cy+$height/2, $start, $end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you were asking, but it's easy to draw pie charts with Google Chart API http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

[image]